# where will I find the android apps published for smartphone?

Tags: android

where will I find the  android apps published for smartphone? My apps are published on 23rd i.e day before yesterday   but are not visible in the google play store?

why is it so Iam searching on the pc as of now . I dont have android device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you publish your app now ,you can find your app on the store soonly **about 2 hours**.
but if you already published more than 6-7 hours and still you can not see your app on the web with this link

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=[your app package name]
```

if you see your app on web but dont see your app on your phone , probably in your manifest.xml there is a rule which your phone does not have that hardware or specifications.Or the problem is `minimumsdk version` .

Comment: But  Iam unable to see Give me the link to  find the apps published ?

Comment: can you write this link on web (replace your package name)

Comment: @Srk2k14 and can you see the your app in prod in your developer console

Comment: Thank you   very much Iam seeing my apps now  at the given link

Comment: Till now I tried with app name directly I could'nt find my app.

Comment: Yes I will. it is asking me to wait 2 min

Comment: ok I am very happy to solve your question , see you on another stackoverflow question :D

Comment: Now is it ok  I will ask one question tmomorrow again

Answer (score 1):

take a look at your developers console if there is an error it should show you there.  Other wise it should come up in about 1 to 2 hours.

See this site
https://play.google.com/apps/publish/
you should see your app there and be able to see if there are any errors with the app.